# Azure DevOps : while using Release Pipeline in classic mode, I'm not able to pass the value of a variable to other tasks

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have to store the value of $pipeline.variables.res.value in new variable in release pipeline and then have to use that new variable in rest of the stages and tasks in release pipeline.
I'm working with classic pipelines.
I'm trying below code:

```
  Set-Variable -Name abc -Value $pipeline.variables.res.value
  Write-Host "New Value:" $abc
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=xyz;isoutput=true]$abc"
  Write-Host "New Value:" $abc
```

Output:
Not able to see any xyz variable in release pipeline. Also, on calling below commands in different tasks, I'm not getting any value as an output.

```
Input: Write-Host "New Value:" $xyz
       Write-Host "New Value:" $abc

Output:2022-09-19T09:04:56.4561806Z New Value: 
       2022-09-19T09:04:56.4594657Z New Value:
```

Please help in this.

Comment: You should use `$(xyz)` in order to print the variable value. This expression should be inside the quotes  `Write-Host "New Value: $(xyz)"`

Comment: Not working with this too..

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not structured correctly. This will not work because of all instructions in one task:

```
Set-Variable -Name abc -Value $pipeline.variables.res.value
Write-Host "New Value:" $abc
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=xyz;isoutput=true]$abc"
Write-Host "New Value:" $xyz
```

You have to consume your variable in a next task like:

```
TASK 1
  Set-Variable -Name abc -Value $pipeline.variables.res.value
  Write-Host "New Value:" $abc
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=xyz;isoutput=true]$abc"

TASK 2
  Write-Host "New Value: $(xyz)"
```

[image]

Comment: I'm doing the same thing, consuming the variable in next task but it is showing blank output. I'm working in release pipeline not in build pipeline.

Comment: @gauravsharma Release and build pipelines use the same methods. GeralexGR is right: you have to use `Write-Host "New Value: $(xyz)"`. Additionally, try to add xyz as a variable in your release pipeline in the Variables tab. There is a good sample in YAML format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax